# How can I copy a array of strings into an unmanaged char double pointer?

Tags: c#, char, marshalling, unmanaged-memory

I have a `char**` in a C struct which is allocated in the C code as a **Nx128** matrix. In C# I have an array of strings and I want to copy this array to the char double pointer, without reallocating anything. I tried this:

```
public void StringArrayToPtr(IntPtr ptr, string[] array) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        char[] chars = (array[i] + '\0').ToCharArray();

        Marshal.Copy(chars, 0, IntPtr.Add(ptr, 128*i), chars.Length);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. **Does somebody know how to perform such a copy ?**

UPDATE:

Here is how my `char** names` is allocated in the C code for 3 items: `names = (char **) MallocArray2D (3, 128, sizeof ( char ));`

Here is the details of the `MallocArray2D` method:

```
void ** MallocArray2D (
     int  n1,
     int  n2,
     int  size_elem )
{
    void ** p2;
    void * p1;
    size_t i;

    p1 = (void *) malloc (size_elem * n1 * n2); 

    p2 = (void **) malloc (n1 * sizeof ( void * ));


    for ( i = 0 ; i < n1 ; i++ )
    {
        p2[i] = (char *) p1 + size_elem * n2 * i;
    }

    return p2;
}
```

This `MallocArray2D` method is called into a `MallocImage` which is exposed in my C# code.

Here is the `MallocImage` method interesting part in C code:

```
int MallocImage (
     IMAGE *  image,
     int           nxyz,
     int           nvar )
{
    //... Allocating others objects

    image->names = (char **) MPDSMallocArray2D ( nvar, 128, sizeof ( char ));

}
```

Now my C# exposed `MallocImage` method:

```
[DllImport(DLL_PATH, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int MallocImage([In, Out]Image image, int nXYZ, int nVar);

// My Image class
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class Image {

    private IntPtr names;

    public string[] Names {

        set {ArrayOfStringToPtr(names, value);}

    }

    // Constructor
    public Image(int nVar, int nXYZ) {

        MallocImage(this, nXYZ, nVar);

    }

}


// Somewhere else in my code
image.Names = new string[] {"porosity", "duplicity", "facies"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Still an important part is missing : How do you call the `MallocArray2D` from the C# code? Also assuming you are, are you using the `p2` pointer in the `StringArrayToPtr` method?

Comment: The pointer I use in the `StringArrayToPtr` method is the `IntPtr names` of my C# class. I guess it corresponds to the `p2` pointer, through the Marshalling process

Comment: Can you verify that the `IntPtr names` of the `Image` class match to the pointer in you `IMAGE` struct? If not please post your `IMAGE` struct.

Comment: The two pointers match.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `System.Char` is a unicode 16 bits character [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.char.aspx)]. You probably work with ASCII string.

The pointer arithmetic seems wrong here, since you are working with *a pointer who points to an array of three pointers* you probably need to get the address of the string using : `Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, i * IntPtr.Size)` thus the resulting code will be :

```
public static void StringArrayToPtr(IntPtr ptr, string[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        byte[] chars = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(array[i] + '\0');
        Marshal.Copy(chars, 0, Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, i * IntPtr.Size), chars.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: I debug the `char** names` in the C code and `names[0]` returns this : "<Bad Ptr>"

Comment: Is your `names` array allocated correctly? Also does the pointer you use in the C# code matches the address of `names`? If the answers are yes then you will have to show your C code and describe the interaction between the both (When the allocation occurs, how do you retrieve the pointer, When are you trying to set the data, etc...)

Comment: The `&names` in C and `&ptr` in C# don't seem do match. Is that the way to control the pointer addresses ? I also update my answer

Comment: It works fine !! Thank you very much. I knew I had to retrieve the pointer but didn't know how to do it. Thx again.