# How to convert string[] to char**?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I have a library I'm dependent on that receives a struct with `char**` as one of the function's arguments.

I want to have a wrapper that receives a `List<string>` (or any `string[]` for that matter) and creates a `char**` to put in that struct. The compiler is OK with my code, but I'm really not sure I got the `fixed` and `unsafe` concepts right, and I'm afraid of unexpected consequences:

```cs
InternalAttributeKeys attrKeys;  // has { (char**) .keys , (int) .count }
unsafe 
{
    char*[] chars = new char*[keys.Count];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count; ++i)
    {
        fixed (char* c = keys[i].ToCharArray())
        {
            chars[i] = c;
        }
    }
    fixed (char** keysPtr = chars)
    {
        attrKeys.keys = keysPtr;
    }
}
attrKeys.count = (uint) keys.Count;
return attrKeys;
```

Did I get it right?

Is there generally a better way to send a `char**` (for instance, can I send a `char*[]` instead and expect C# to do the conversion behind the scenes)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's safe ... pointers are fixed inside `fixed` after you are outside `fixed` memory managment may move the object to another point in memory ... if you have a point to free this structure after it's used in unmanaged code I would use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal/Free`

Comment: @Selvin but does it make the pointer invalid if it moves? I thought `fixed` only guarantees continuity, which I don't need here anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this, seems to address my question from a different perspective (and it looks more robust than whatever I came up with):

[How can I copy a array of strings into an unmanaged char double pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091618/how-can-i-copy-a-array-of-strings-into-an-unmanaged-char-double-pointer)

I will use the `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and create an `IDisposable` object to manage this memory.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Linq

```
        var charArray = array.SelectMany(x => x.ToCharArray());
```

Or

```
  string[] S = {"aaaaa",
                "bbbbb",
                "ccccc"};
  char[] C = string.Join(string.Empty, S).ToCharArray();
```

Comment: no, he can't ... he needs `char[][]` not all strings in one `char[]` .... also you can't just send marshalled `char[]` when unmanaged side expects pointer to pointer